# How to connect Retool local docker under WSL to non docker local GQL?

Tags: docker, graphql, retool

I can't find a way to connect a self hosted local instance of Retool (which runs 5 docker containers) to a (non dockerized) GraphQL server running on the same machine.

I am using WSL for windows for both.

I've tried the answer to a similar question here [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)
`http://host.docker.internal:4000/graphql`

and have tried
`extra_hosts: - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`

Which don't seem to work

also, docker will not accept adding these flags
`
`` --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -d```

I was hoping for test connection to work in Retool, either with

`http://host.docker.internal:4000/graphql`

or

`http://localhost:4000/graphql`